# Convert Percent to Odds Ratio and Reverse

Tags: formula, probability

Easy softball for someone to knock out of the park: what is the correct coding formula for computing an odds ratio to a percent, and a percent to an odds ratio? Example:

```
Odds to Percent
1 in 8192 = 0.0001220

Percent to Odds
0.0001220 = 1 in 8192
```

Programming language is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

```
odds_to_percent(a, b):
    return str(float(a)/b)

percent_to_odds(x):
    return '1 in ' + str(1.0/x)
```

Not sure what exactly you need. There are many decisions about rounding and co.

Comment: You sure Odds to percent is not "return (double)a / (b + a)"? Rhetorical question. By the way, phantom downvotes are going to make me close this question.

Comment: Define odds then. I'm describing the *1 in X*, not *1 vs. X (parts)*.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
public struct Odds
    {
        private int _a;
        private int _b;


        public int A
        {
            get
            {
                return _a;
            }
        }

        public int B
        {
            get
            {
                return _b;
            }
        }

        public Odds(int a, int b)
        {
            this._a = a;
            this._b = b;
        }

        public Odds(double percent)
        {
            Odds odds = FromPercent(percent);
            this._a = odds.A;
            this._b = odds.B;
        }

        public Odds Invert()
        {
            return new Odds(_b, _a);
        }

        public double ToPercent()
        {
            return ToPercent(_a, _b);
        }

        public static double ToPercent(int a, int b)
        {
            return ((double)a / (b + a));
        }

        public static Odds FromPercent(double percent)
        {
            int multiplier = GetDecimalMultiplier(percent);
            return new Odds(1, (multiplier - (int)(percent * multiplier)) / (int)(percent * multiplier));
        }

        private static int GetDecimalMultiplier(double n)
        {
            if (n > 0.01)
            {
                return 100;
            }
            if (n > 0.001)
            {
                return 100000;
            }
            if (n > 0.0001)
            {
                return 100000000;
            }
            throw new Exception("Number too small!");
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return A + "-" + B;
        }
    }
```

Odds to Percent:

```
    public static double ToPercent(int a, int b)
    {
        return ((double)a / (b + a));
    }
```

Percent to Odds(May not be perfect)

```
        public static Odds FromPercent(double percent)
        {
            int multiplier = GetDecimalMultiplier(percent);
            return new Odds(1, (multiplier - (int)(percent * multiplier)) / (int)(percent * multiplier));
        }

        private static int GetDecimalMultiplier(double n)
        {
            if (n > 0.01)
            {
                return 100;
            }
            if (n > 0.001)
            {
                return 100000;
            }
            if (n > 0.0001)
            {
                return 100000000;
            }
            throw new Exception("Number too small!");
        }
```